# How to save a complete webpage in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to save exactly the version of a page that I am currently seeing. This means the complete page that was generated after running all the site scripts and therefore has all the css,js files and images.

I tried it on an output from woorank.com but I am missing quite a lot of css images and the local copy has these problems (a shortened error log):

```
Failed to load resource file:///C:/assets/img/css/header_icon_lang.png
body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollTop' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollTop' only if in quirks mode.
body.scrollLeft is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollLeft' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollLeft' only if in quirks mode.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.woorank.com/assets/mustache/report/parts.mustache?v=4. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. 
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null'). core:rpc:shindig.random:shindig.sha1.js?c=2:838
```

Comment: You can print it to PDF "as is".

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Internet Explorer? it'll save a whole page...
But if you persist on chrome you can use some extensions:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpage-screenshot/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki?hl=en

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-scrapbook/gokffdfnlmampchciemmflgbckijpmlb

Comment: Problem is I have a page opened that is not accessible anymore so I can't switch browsers (or restart mine).

Answer (score 0):

[Teleport Pro](http://www.tenmax.com/teleport/) is a good software to download webpages. It can automate the process and go through all links in a domain or from a specific address. On the other hand, you can try to use Ctrl+S shortcut (save webpage) in web browsers like Chrome, Firefox - they vary in the files that are being saved locally to disk. Another option is wget (there is one compiled for Windows console) which can do the same.